# Убрать \n и пробелы при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Имеется код на python который парсит названия, описания и кол-во звёзд у популярных репозиториев github

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://github.com/trending'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
parse = soup.find_all("article",class_="Box-row")
data=[]
for repo in parse:
    name=repo.find('h2',class_="h3 lh-condensed").find("a").get("href")

    data.append(name)
    describe=repo.find("p",class_="col-9 color-fg-muted my-1 pr-4")
    try:
        describe= describe.text
        data.append(describe)
    except:
        describe="-"
        data.append(describe)

    
    star=repo.find("div",class_="f6 color-fg-muted mt-2").find("a",class_="Link Link--muted d-inline-block mr-3").text
    data.append(star)
print(data)
```

Но при выводе списка получаю это:

```
['/spdustin/ChatGPT-AutoExpert', '\n       Supercharged Custom Instructions for ChatGPT (non-coding) and ChatGPT Advanced Data Analysis (coding). \n    ', '\n\n\n\n        1,880\n', '/PWhiddy/PokemonRedExperiments', '\n      Playing Pokemon Red with Reinforcement Learning\n    ', '\n\n\n\n        2,197\n', '/LazyVim/LazyVim', '\n      Neovim config for the lazy\n    ', '\n\n\n\n        9,524\n', '/ton-community/tact-challenge', '-', '\n\n\n\n        74\n', '/pi-hole/pi-hole', '\n      A black hole for Internet advertisements\n    ', '\n\n\n\n        43,916\n'.........
```

Много переносов строк (`\n`) и пробелов, хотя для количества звёзд должно выводиться только число, а для описания - только текст без всяких переносов.

##### P.S. Спарсить только число у меня не получилось

Comment: Что мешает удалить их *стандартными* методами Python? Типа `replace()`?

Comment: Делал describe.replace('\n', '') ничего не изменилось

Comment: Раз так не работает, пробовали пройтись по списку в конце с реплейсом?

Comment: А ещё есть `strip`, возможно он любые пробельные символы удаляет. Но точно не помню.

Comment: @CrazyElf дал ответ, а затем уже прочёл ваш комментарий:) Да, тоже вспомнил про `strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
data=[i.replace("\n","").strip() for i in data]
print(data)
```

Вывод:

```
['/spdustin/ChatGPT-AutoExpert', ' Supercharged Custom Instructions for ChatGPT (non-coding) and ChatGPT Advanced Data Analysis (coding).', '1,880', '/PWhiddy/PokemonRedExperiments', ...]
```

---

##### UPD: Как подсказал @CrazyElf, можно убрать `replace()`:

```
data=[i.strip() for i in data]
print(data)
```

Comment: Да `strip` и без `replace` для данных строк справляется )

Comment: @CrazyElf да? В смысле `\n` тоже убирает? Круто, не знал)

Comment: @ÇℏėτᶄắɤẵÇℏėτɤᶉᶄắ немного извенив код это перестало работать. Сделал добавление списка по другому   ```data.append([name, describe,star])```. object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @SP595 так чем он вам не нравится? Зачем изменять?

Comment: Нужно чтобы для каждого репа в отдельном подсписке значения были.